# Remove brand from Wear OS Watch faces

Tags: android-wear

I just bought a Fossil Gen 5 Carlyle. Before this, I used a Huawei Watch. I noticed they have a lot of builtin watch faces in common, so this must be builtin to Wear OS. The difference is, the watch faces on the Fossil watch show the Fossil logo, whereas the Huawei Watch doesn’t.

I don’t like having the brand name on my watch face all the time. Can it be removed (while using the builtin watch faces)?